# Tag usage within links/anchors

Tags: html, semantics

Which of the examples is considered to be semantically correct?

1. `<a href="http://example.com/"><strong>Example</strong></a>`
2. `<strong><a href="http://example.com/">Example</a></strong>`

Of course applies to any other formatting tag like `<u>`, `<em>` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. both are inline elements which can contain other inline elements (except there own tag) `<strong><strong></strong></strong>` is **incorrect** but any of [this list](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html) can be used inside of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Both are; both elements are inline elements.